# Как удалить элемент двумерного массива?

Tags: python

Есть фиксированный массив.
Для примера:

```
cards = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Каким образом удалить, например, `1` в этом массиве?
В интернете искал, однако там более сложные для понимания примеры, а мне нужен просто метод удаления элементов многомерного массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `del` - введите эту команду:

```
del cards[1]
```

А если удалить элемент 2 в элементе 1 (в данном случае цифру 1, как у вас в примере), введите:

```
del cards[0][1]
```

***Меньше места занимает))***

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТ-версия-3-8 неверно :) ```del cards[1]``` удаляет элемент номер 1 в массиве cards. Результат выполнения равен ```[ [0, 1] ]```

Comment: @alex почему :)

Comment: Вроде всё правильно, проверил

Comment: ```del cards[1]``` удаляет элемент номер 1 в массиве cards. Результат выполнения равен ```[ [0, 1] ]```

Comment: Ну да)  А `del cards[0][0]` удаляет элемент 1 в элементе 1

Comment: так он просил удалить цифру ```1```

Comment: del cards[1] - это же всё равно неверно

Comment: Верно, просто удалит сразу числа `0` и `1`

Answer (score 1):

А, думал через `pop` неправильно, а оказалось ошибка в коде)

просто делаем:

```
cards[0].pop(1)
```

Comment: Только забывать не надо, что `pop` ещё возвращает элемент. Если он вам не нужен, то лучше `del` ;)